# Does anyone recognize this surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Dear all,

in some of my work I am considering the algebraic surface given implicitly by

$$
    z^2\left(1-x+\frac{z^2}{4}\right) = y^2.
$$

Maybe this surface is known? Does anyone recognize it and/or point me to some literature?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think it has a special name, but it's a singular quartic whose resolution/normalization (take the substitution $\alpha=y/z$) is a smooth quadric in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Answer (score 13):

Your surface is actually a **Whitney umbrella**.

To see that, just perform the  following substitution (which is just a translation):

$$x =1+\frac{z^2}{4} -t.$$

After this, your surface is defined by the simpler equation:

$$z^2 t =y^2.$$

This is exactly the canonical form of the **Whitney umbrella**. The Whitney umbrella is a singular surface in $\mathbb{C}^3$ which looks like a self-intersecting plane. It has  a  line of double  points at $z=y=0$ and the singularity worsen to a pinch point at the origin  $z=y=t=0$. You can resolve it by  blowing-up the double line.

The Whitney umbrella is studied in many books of algebraic geometry as an example of a surface with a pinch point and a first tricky example of blow-up: it shows that blowing-up the worse singularity is not the best way to smooth a space (if you blow-up the pinch points you will again get the same equation). 
 In classical singular theory, it is an example of a singular surface which does not have a regular Whitney stratification. It also appears very naturally in the study of elliptic fibration in the context of string theory (more precisely F-theory) when one consider "Sen's weak coupling limit" which gives the orientifold limit of F-theory at weak coupling.

Comment: Nice!  For a picture: http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~zca/Reports_on_ca/29/paper_html/whitney-umbrella.gif .